# UTL_MAIL message attribute calling OWA_UTIL.cellsprint procedure Oracle

Tags: sql, database, oracle, plsql

Hi I have the following html snippet, I want to send via email in my procedure.
How do I put that in my message attribute of UTL_MAIL.
Should I put it in some variable and if so how?

If there is any better way, I would love to explore that too.I have two options below.I am not able to make the MESSAGE attribute work.

```
OPTION 1
   DECLARE
    BEGIN
    UTL_MAIL.SEND (
      sender       => 'xxx@yyy',
      recipients   => 'abc@xyz',
      subject      => 'Hi',
      MESSAGE      => 
      OWA_UTIL.cellsprint (p_theQuery =>'SELECT   a1,b1,c1,d1
                     FROM     test1
                     WHERE    a1 > 1
                     ORDER BY a1',
      p_max_rows=>'10',p_format_numbers => NULL),

      mime_type    => 'text/html; charset=us-ascii');

    END;

    ----------------------------------------------------------------
    OPTION2
    Declare
        Begin
        ....
        ......
        UTL_MAIL.SEND (
          sender       => 'xxx@yyy',
          recipients   => 'abc@xyz',
          subject      => 'Hi',
          MESSAGE      => ***
          mime_type    => 'text/html; charset=us-ascii');
        *** 
        HTP.P ('<HTML>');
         HTP.P ('<HEAD>');
         HTP.P ('<TITLE>Duplicate Records</TITLE>');
         HTP.P ('</HEAD>');
         HTP.P ('<BODY>');
         HTP.P ('<H1>Duplicate Records</H1>');
         HTP.P ('<TABLE BORDER="1 ">');
         HTP.P ('<TR><TH>HIERARCHY</TH><TH>Org Long NAME</TH></TR>');

         FOR idx IN (SELECT   a1,b1,c1,d1
                     FROM     test1
                     WHERE    a1 > 1
                     ORDER BY a1 LOOP
          HTP.P ('<TR>');
          HTP.P ('<TD>' || idx.a1 || '</TD>');
          HTP.P ('<TD>' || idx.b1 || '</TD>');
          HTP.P ('<TD>' || idx.c1 || '</TD>');
          HTP.P ('<TD>' || idx.d1 || '</TD>');
          HTP.P ('</TR>');
         END LOOP;

         HTP.P ('</TABLE>');
         HTP.P ('</BODY>');
         HTP.P ('</HTML>');


        END;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

UTL_MAIL.send's `message` is just a VARCHAR2 parameter, it takes a string as a parameter.

`HTP.P` and `OWA_UTIL.cellsprint` are procedures, not functions, so they cannot be used to pass a value to the mail. They're designed for use in a web-based application, and not suitable for other purposes like mail.

You could use the functions in `HTF` if you want, but in your case you've already written your html so you may as well just pass it directly to message:

```
UTL_MAIL.SEND (
      sender       => 'xxx@yyy',
      recipients   => 'abc@xyz',
      subject      => 'Hi',
      MESSAGE      => '<HTML>...'
      mime_type    => 'text/html; charset=us-ascii');
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Jeff for replying...Appreciate your time