# Get HTML output of results of a SELECT statement

Tags: html, oracle, plsql

I'm using Pl/SQL and Oracle Application Express 4.1 on Oracle Database 11g.

I've been trying send an email including HTML output of the result of a `SELECT` statement I have. I found the `owa_utils.cellsprint` function that prints out HTML, but I'm hoping to actually get the HTML in a big varchar or clob returned from a similar function. Then I can add some more text of my own and eventually send the email with the table inside. I searched around, but couldn't find anything besides the cellsprint function.

So what I have is this: 
`owa_utils.cellsprint('SELECT col1, col2, col3 FROM my_table WHERE condition');`

But what I would ideally like is something similar to this: 
`l_clob := some_function('SELECT col1, col2, col3 FROM mytable WHERE condition');`

Then I would add some more HTML to l_clob and send the email.
Is there any way to do this without writing my own function to iterate through the result set and create the table using `<tr>` and `<td>` myself?

Comment: I'm afraid there is no such thing out of box. You have likely already seen e.g. [Within a PL/SQL procedure, wrap a query or refcursor in HTML table](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7742656) and [UTL_MAIL message attribute calling OWA_UTIL.cellsprint procedure Oracle](http://stackoverflow.com/q/16470518) ? Have you checked what [Alexandria PL/SQL Utility Library](http://code.google.com/p/plsql-utils/) has to offer ?

Comment: Thanks, I'll check out the Utility library.